# Need to know about the RAM and the processor relation

Tags: windows-7, memory, cpu, 32-vs-64-bit

Currently I am using XP 32 bit with 4 GB RAM and Core i3 processor. I am using this system for the multi PC. Now I wanted to upgrade my CPU with the 8 GB RAM or even more and also use  Windows 7 64 bit. Does this makes my CPU faster than before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are making the common mistake of calling the computer as a whole the CPU.  The central processing unit (CPU) is the "brains" of the computer and will run at the same speed, regardless of how much memory you have.

Generally speaking, more memory will make your computer run faster.  8 GB is plenty for most people.  You say you are using it for "multi PC" which I am *assuming* is for virtual machines.  If that is the case, you need to consider how many virtual PCs you intend on running simultaneously, as well as what their recommended minimum values of memory.  For example, you could run 3 virtual Linux OSs with 2 GB of RAM for each, leaving 2 for the host machine.  That may work for you, or you might need more.  Its something you need to figure out.

Comment: Yeah i am using for the virtual machine more specifically thin client. I am currently facing the problem mainly due to java running for the video download and also If any of the users that i had created is running a game in the facebook then my computer shows the problem. the whole system freezes then i have to restart individual system. For this only i am looking for the change

Comment: @RajeshLtel: You have decent specs. You shouldn't be having those kinds of problems. Before you make drastic changes, you might want to do some troubleshooting. What's your peak CPU temperature? Have you ruled out hardware problems?

Answer (score 3):

Yes and no.

No in that more ram will not make your CPU faster - your CPU is still doing the same amount of work.  (A CPU has a very specific meaning, being the "Core i3 processor" in your case.  The entire box, which contains the motherboard, ram, cpu, hard drive, power supply etc is sometimes called the CPU by people who don't know better, but they are misusing the term).

Yes in that it probably will make your system faster.  By making more memory available to the system more data can be cached in RAM, so there will be less hard drive activity, and less swapping to memory so your system will perform better.   It is also likely that Windows 7 will perform better then XP - but this is not to do with a faster CPU.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i'll look forward to what i can do considering your statement as well.